# Filter by dates in all levels of mapping Association hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have multiple level of associated tables and their entities as below

*Entity Department which has list of associated EmployeeDepAssoc*

```
@Entity
public class Department
{
....
@OneToMany
List<EmployeeDepAssoc> employeeAssoc;
}
```

*Entity EmployeeDepAssoc contains department and employee association and their validity period (start date and end date)*

```
public class EmployeeDepAssoc
{
....
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
Department department;

@OneToOne
Employee employee;

Date startDate;

Date endDate;

}
```

*Entity Employee which has again list of associated PayStructure*

```
@Entity
public class Employee
{
....
@OneToMany
List<PayStructure> payStructures;
}
```

*Entity PayStructure contains employee and payStructure association and their validity period (start date and end date)*

```
@Entity
public class PayStructure
{
....
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne
Department Employee;

Double salary;

Date startDate;

Date endDate;
}
```

When user requests for list of departments I have to give only data which is valid by user given date / current date in all levels.(ie. I have to filter by start date and end date in all levels). What is the way for this in Spring Boot JPA environment

*Note: I just avoided some annotations like @JoinColumn here in this post. But I am using that in my code*

Comment: what have you tried so far. How are you querying ?  using JPARepository?

Comment: Yeah I am using JPARepository but this filter not yet implemented.

Comment: show your repositoryclass with methods for which you want filter to be applied

Comment: Lets say custom method _findByDates(Date startDate, Date endDate)_ of _DepartmentRepository_ should filter and give data valid by given dates in all of its associaton level. I am ready to use either custom implementation of that repository(_DepartmentRepositoryCustom_ ,_DepartmentRepositoryImpl_ ) or _@Query_ annotation

Comment: Try this `findByEmployeeAssoc_StartDateAndEmployeeAssoc_EndDateAndEmployeeAssoc_Employee_PayStructures_StartDateAndEmployeeAssoc_Employee_PayStructures_Enddate(Date startDate, Date endDate, Date startDate, Date endDate)`

Comment: It is generating query with the given condition to fetch _Department_ entity     and while it is querying for mapped _Employee_ entities it will again fetch all _payStructures_ associated with it.  So is any way to attach a filter to the hibernate generated queries to fetch associations

Comment: don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: the request is to make the join relationship between 2 objects fetched automatically using a filter with Hibernate ? (personally never seen such thing implemented and would like to know in case possible)

Comment: Even I can go with _@Filter_ annotation. If I mention a filter in _Employee_ entity above       @OneToMany
    List<PayStructure> payStructures;    Is there any way to enable it while querying _Department_ entity

Comment: The above approach worked finally